# Proof that diads of basis vectors form a basis in the space of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, dual-spaces

It seems to be a well-known fact [1] that basis vectors $|e_i\rangle$ of *finite-dimensional* Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$ and the vectors of corresponding dual basis $\langle e_j| \in \mathbb{H} \to_{lin} \mathbb{C}$ could be combined in diads $|e_i\rangle\langle e_j| \in \mathbb{H}\to_{lin}\mathbb{H}$ such that $\forall |v\rangle\in\mathbb{H} : (|e_i\rangle\langle e_j|) |v\rangle = \langle e_j|v\rangle|e_i\rangle$ where $\langle .|.\rangle \in \mathbb{C}$ denotes the inner product in $\mathbb{H}$.

How to proof that such $|e_i\rangle\langle e_j|$ actually form a basis in the space of linear functions $\mathbb{H}\to_{lin}\mathbb{H}$, that is $\forall f\in \mathbb{H}\to_{lin}\mathbb{H}: \exists F_{ij}\in\mathbb{C}: f = \sum_{ij}F_{ij}|e_i\rangle\langle e_j|$ ?

[1] - [Vannucci, Tensor Algebra and Tensor Analysis](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03298805/document), page 8

--

Updates: Added a note about finite dimensionality of $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: This is in general not true, these operators span only the compact operators of the space. This is only true if $H$ is a finite space, in which case I invite you to think about this interms of matrices.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a note about finiteness. Still I would be happy to see a more abstract proof, if possible.

Comment: @Grwlf As far as abstract proofs go: one point of interest is that non-compact operators cannot be represented using the diad (Schauder) basis. To see this, it suffices to note that a each diad has finite rank and is therefore compact, and that a convergent (in operator norm) sequence of compact operators has a compact limit

Comment: Another point of interest is that every compact operator **can** be represented using the diad basis. To see this, it suffices to note that every compact operator can be expressed as the limit of a sequence of finite-rank operators and that every finite rank operator can be expressed as a sum of diads.

Comment: The first of these points can be addressed by pointing to any standard functional analysis reference. The second would probably merit its own separate question.

Comment: Definitions are our friends in proving mathematical statements.  To be a basis means both linear independence and spanning need to be proven.  However when dealing with finite dimensional vector spaces of known *dimensional size*, one can make do with showing only one of those two properties, provided the number of basis elements is matched to the size of the dimension.